# problem with jetty classpath when working with gwt and jsp

Tags: java, gwt, netbeans, classpath, jetty

Hi
I have created an ajax application using GWT.
And I have created just one jsp file that connects to my data access layer to get some information to show them to user.

In my jsp file I have imported some of my classes in that jsp file to use them.
When I call that jsp file in the development mode, jetty creates a file with the extension of .class near all of my java files!!!! whereas my compiled java files are located at /war/WEB-INF/classes but jetty doesn't understand that where are they and creates a .class file near each java file.

I'm trying using netbeans and free form project template of netbeans!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your project configuration, possibly you've specified a wrong web folder for Jetty.
2. Try to use Eclipse and the Google Eclipse plug-in. I guess, it's more stable and guaranteed to work.